# select all input value in input type number

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html

i have this  on a webpage.
When a user click in the input element, i want the input elements value to be auto selected.

I can do this by making onclick event to this.select() like shown below

```
<input type="number" onclick="this.select();" >
```

This will selected the value in firefox, chrome and IE. but it won't in safari. an i wanna make this usable for Iphones too.
tough google search i found a javascript method that safari support thats look something like this

```
document.getElementById(inputElementsId).setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
```

But it's not support for input type "number".
So is there a other way to get this running?

As always, thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

when you say safari, i suppose you mean the iOS safari ? Anyway, on touch device, the click event might not be fired but the touch event instead. You can use these :

```
$("input[type='number']").on('click touchstart', function () {
    $(this).select();
});
```

Comment: This would throw an error... something like: The input element's type ('number') does not support selection

Answer (score -3):

If you have to use `document.getElementById()` then just give your input an ID!

`<input id=num_input type="number" onclick="this.select();" >`

Then you can select it with `document.getElementById('num_input');`

Comment: OP is trying to select the value in the input, not javascript select element by id